# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker doesn't show calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, calendar

I've included the following in my page:

In the `<head>`

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified jQuery Core -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Bottom of `<body>`

```
<!-- Moments.js minified CDN -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap datepicker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Then I used jQuery to turn my form's input field into the datepicker:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

The input field got styled like a date picker(field with a calendar icon at the end), but when I click anywhere on that field or the icon the calendar doesn't show up.

I've re-read the [Installation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#manual) tutorial but I don't see anything missing.

Comment: Load jquery.min.js before bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

By

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.14.30/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

You should get `TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function` in the browser console.

Because you include only datepicker not datetimepicker.

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/rerusurego/edit?html,output)

Comment: Also had to add CSS for datetime-picker, otherwise the calendar looks like garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Add **datetimepicker1** To  `<input type='text' class="form-control" id="datetimepicker1" />`

and `$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();` not `$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();`

Wokring here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">-->
</head>
<body>


<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' >
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id="datetimepicker1" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- Latest compiled and minified jQuery Core -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you opened the browser console,you would have seen an exception error in the console,like `bootstrap JS requires jquery` or so

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified jQuery Core -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
```

this should work